# Microsft SQLHelper vs Dapper

Tags: dapper, sqlhelper

I am new to C#, programming for less than a year. Until now I have been using the Micrsoft SQLHelper class. (copy of text header below) I recently came across Dapper.

Question is, should I switch to using Dapper ?

Although the SQLHelper class has worked with no issues, I don't know how old it is and I don't have enough experience to determine whether I should switch to using Dapper for xyz reasons. Is Dapper the preferred long term solution?

Thanks

> // Microsoft Data Access Application Block for .NET // SQLHelper.cs //
> // This file contains the implementations of the SqlHelper and
> SqlHelperParameterCache // classes.

Answer (score 1):

Is EntLib doing what you need and not inconveniencing you? Then: perhaps stay with it. Dapper would probably be *more convenient* in a lot of ways, and EntLib is arguably taking a complex API (ADO.NET) and *making it more complex* (as opposed to Dapper which aims to make things simpler for the caller), but: if the code works... *shrug*.

If you were starting from scratch, I'd 100% say "don't go near EntLib with a barge pole, Dapper is fine" (disclosure: I'm a little biased), but: if your code is working today, probably best not to touch it unless you have time to fix any problems you get while moving cogs.